# How can I write the following reactions and label them?

Tags: equations, chemfig

I would like to write those following reactions and label them like equation mode. How can I do that?

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Please note that you are typically required to post at least something that you created on your own to show that you tried to solve you problem in some way. Anyway, I hope my answer will help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just put some `\chemfig`s into `subequations` and `equation` environments:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{chemfig, amsmath}

\begin{document}

\setcounter{equation}{6}
\setchemfig{atom sep=2em, arrow coeff=.5}

\begin{subequations}

\begin{equation}
  \schemestart
    \chemfig{CO} \+ \chemfig{Pt} 
    \arrow(.mid east--.mid west) 
    \chemfig{Pt-[2]C~[2]O}
  \schemestop
  \quad \text{(linear-bonded)}
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
  \schemestart
    \chemfig{CO} \+ \chemfig{Pt Pt} 
    \arrow(.mid east--.mid west) 
    \chemfig{Pt-[:72.5]C(-[:-72.5]Pt)=[2]O}
  \schemestop
  \quad \text{(bridge-bonded)}
\end{equation}

\end{subequations}

\begin{subequations}

\begin{equation}
  \schemestart
    \chemfig{CO CO} \+ \chemfig{Pt Pt(-[2,,1,]H)-[2,,2,]H} 
    \arrow(.mid east--.mid west) 
    \chemfig{Pt Pt(-[2,,1,]C~[2]O)-[2,,2,]C~[2]O} \+ \chemfig{H2}
  \schemestop
  \quad \text{(linear-bonded)}
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
  \schemestart
    \chemfig{CO} \+ \chemfig{Pt Pt(-[2,,1,]H)-[2,,2,]H} 
    \arrow(.mid east--.mid west) 
    \chemfig{Pt-[:72.5]C(-[:-72.5]Pt)=[2]O} \+ \chemfig{H2}
  \schemestop
  \quad \text{(bridge-bonded)}
\end{equation}

\end{subequations}

\end{document}
```

[image]